# Auto hide Table Content By Default

Tags: javascript

I have a list of data in html table, the thing i want is to hide its content as if it does not contain any data. When the user enter the matched keyword, it'll show up the table contents.

I need to know how to modify this javascript according to my situation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value.toUpperCase();
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)');
  trs.forEach(tr => tr.style.display = [...tr.children].find(td => td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) ? '' : 'none');
}
```

EDIT: Source For My HTML File
https://pastebin.com/cx0DtfDJ

[image: Auto Hide By Default]

[image: Content Showed Up After Matched keyword is entered]

Comment: it is better to use datatables

Comment: think i'll stick with this javascript first.

Comment: can you create a js fiddle for the same